# How do I show the first letter of the_title in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have got this code from another post, found here: [Get first word in string php the_title WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659452/get-first-word-in-string-php-the-title-wordpress):

```
<?php $title = get_the_title(); // This must be!, because this is the return - the_title  
would be echo
$title_array = explode(' ', $title);
$first_word = $title_array[0];

echo $first_word;
?>
```

This should grab the first word but how do I modify it to show the very first letter of the_title in Wordpress?

Answer (score 3):

`echo $first_word[0];`

or

`echo $title[0];`

Or perhaps something that makes more sense:

`echo substring($title, 0, 1);`

Note that you can't do `get_the_title()[0]` because it's a syntax error.

Comment: If that line causes a syntax error what should I use instead?

Comment: Okay so i'm a little confused, sorry. Will my code look like this then?
    <?php $title = get_the_title();

    $title_array = explode(' ', $title);
    $first_word = $title_array[0];

    echo substring($title, 0, 1);
    ?>

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

echo `echo $title[0];` or  `echo substr($title,0,1);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$title = get_the_title();
echo $title[0];   //print first letter


?>
```

Another option

```
<?php

$title = get_the_title();
echo substr($title,0,1);   //takes first character from $title and print //


?>
```