# Return words before specific character from wordpress the_title();

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, implode

I am trying to get words before specific character in WordPress `the_title()`.

My WordPress post titles always looks something like this "*How To - Make Things Happen*".

How can I return all the words before the "-" in PHP, for example get "How To" from "How To - Make Things"

I am trying to use all words before "-" and a keyword within the post page.

I have seen a similar solution here: [Get first word in string php the_title WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659452/get-first-word-in-string-php-the-title-wordpress) but it doesn't  fit perfectly as I am trying to get all words before a specific character

Comment: $short=explode('-',$title);
echo $short[0];

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
$title = get_the_title();
$substring = substr($title, 0, strpos($string, '-'));
```

or

```
$title = current(explode('-', get_the_title()));

echo $title['0'];
```

Comment: I am getting only the first letter with this wolution, i want to get everything before the "-"

Comment: try echo $title not echo $title['0']

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the index from above answer by Narek.
Try this:

```
$title = current(explode('-', 'How To - Make Things Happen'));

echo $title;
```

Comment: It works with "How To - Make Things Happen" but how do i make it work with WordPress the_title()

Comment: You just need to pass that variable buddy!
<?php
$the_title = 'How To - Make Things Happen';
$title = current(explode('-', $the_title));

echo $title;

?>

Or even you can pass that whole function there "get_the_title();"

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work, this works: <?php 
$the_title =  get_the_title();
$title = current(explode(' ', $the_title)); 
echo $title; 
?> but this doesnt: <?php 
$the_title =  get_the_title();
$title = current(explode('-', $the_title)); 
echo $title; 
?>

Comment: Try echoing out what get_the_title(); gives to you then try, the following code works fine for me.
`code`
<?php

 $the_title = 'How To - Make Things Happen'; // get_the_title();
 $title = current(explode('-', $the_title));
 echo $title;
?>

Or please provide whole the code you are trying