# Call first word of post title in page template

Tags: php

I want to do exactly what is talked about in this question: [Get first word in string php the_title WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659452/get-first-word-in-string-php-the-title-wordpress?noredirect=1&lq=1)

(I think) I understand that putting this code in functions will trim the title, but how do I actually call it in the page template?

Comment: Open your `functions.php`-file and write a function for the code in the answer. Then you can use it where ever. Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: Yes - I've tried putting the code in functions... but I don't know how to use it. Hence the question

Comment: What do you mean _"how to use it"_? If you wrote a function, surly you know how to call it? It's just a function. Please show us the code you've tried and explain the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress one does not call specialized functions in the template to modify such things as the title (or other data from the database).

Instead Wordpress offers filters to modify the output. See:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title

Example: (in functions.php or some related PHP file from the used theme)

```
function title_first_word( $title, $id = null ) {
    /* optional: check here on which page you are or which template is in use  */
    $titleParts = explode(' ', $title);
    return $titleParts[0];
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'title_first_word', 10, 2 );
```